# compare pointer to character

Tags: c, pointers

I tried to write this thing in C:

```
(*(result+1))!="\0"
```

The compiler said:

> Possible assignment in condition `(*(result+1))=!"\0"`

What is the problem?

Comment: The error shows your operator as `=!` and not `!=`.

Comment: Please post the full code. There are so many pitfalls here.

Comment: I believe you did mean `'\0'` instead of `"\0"`. Note the quotes. The first is a string and the second a single character. Also,you first and second codes are different.

Comment: *(result+1) is the same as result[1] and I'd prefer second form here.

Answer (score 7):

Comparisons in C use the `==` operator.  The single `=` is an assignment.  Besides that, you're trying to compare a pointer to an integer.  The code you have is:

```
(*(result+1))=!"\0"
```

In that expression, `!"\0"` is equal to `0`, so your code is *really* doing:

```
(*(result+1))=0
```

And that's probably not what you want.  For sure it doesn't match what you have there in your "I'm trying to write this expression" example.  I think what you are trying to do is:

```
(*(result+1)) != '\0'
```

Using the `!=` "not equal to" operator.  It just looks like you have written `=!` instead.  Probably just a typo.  Note that I changed the double quotes to single quotes to correct your expression, too.

Editorial note - you don't need the operator at all.  Your expression is equal to:

```
*(result + 1)
```

Which would have saved you the trouble in the first place.

Comment: another words, "what isn't the problem?" ?

Comment: how can you know what the OP wants in the first place?

Comment: @moooeeeep, educated guess.  He said what he was trying to write right there in his question.

Comment: It's just a wild guess that he's trying to compare a pointer (actually assigning) to an integer though. For all we know `(*(result+1))` could be an integer.

Comment: What?  He's clearly trying to compare something to a null character `\0`.  The integer *is* the `*(result+1)`.  The *pointer* is `"\0"`.  The string `"\0"` is *super* non-ideomatic at the absolute best case -a string with *two* null-terminations?  Crazy!

Comment: You do see that his error message and his "I'm trying to do" have `=!` and `!=` swapped, right?  Wait - someone edited his question and changed it.  I just put it back.  I think it makes more sense now.

Comment: Have a look at the edit history. The OP has not clearly stated what he was trying to do. How can you know? His code covers not enough context to make _any_ sense, i.e. no semicolons, what does he do with this condition, what is the type of `result` and what is the content? Honestly, this question should be closed in its current form as it cannot be reasonably answered.

Comment: @moooeeeep, you're the one who changed the OP's question's meaning.  You know the expression is being used in a condition because of the error message, and it's clear what the problem is.  Let's see what the OP says.

Comment: @moooeeeep, edit 1 (the OP's post) clearly shows the mismatch.  Your edit changed them to match, which changes the meaning of the question entirely.  As far as I'm concerned, this is a simple beginner error of confusion with a compiler error due to a typo.  If it's not, I'm sure the OP will clarify for us.

Comment: Actually you are right, my edit was wrong. It should be rolled back to the previous version. As for the intent of the OP, what he asked may not be what he wanted to know. But we can not know this for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are indeed performing a comparison and not an assignment, you need `==` instead of `=`; that is why you're getting the possible assignment message.

Comment: _expr1 != expr2_ is not an assignment.

Comment: @varervarao - someone edited the question and mangled the OP's intent.  It think octopusgrabbus has a reasonable answer given the context of the question at the time he answered it.

Comment: As @CarlNorum stated, I answered based on what I saw in the question. It looked like an assignment to me, not a reversed `!=` operator.